# Gitlab-runner ssh executor. ssh: handshake failed: knownhosts: key mismatch

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to use gitlab-runner to deploy my site on digital ocean with the ssh executor.

In my droplet I have these users:

- root: account with log in disabled only accesed by web console.
- deploy: user account that actually runs the application.
- gitlab-runner: created with gitlab's setup script.

This is the content of `/home/gitlab-runner/.gitlab-runner/config.toml` :

```
concurrent = 1
check_interval = 0
log_level = "debug"
shutdown_timeout = 0

[session_server]
  session_timeout = 1800

[[runners]]
  name = "mpm-staging"
  url = "https://gitlab.com"
  id = 27295584
  token = "redacted"
  token_obtained_at = 2023-08-28T17:25:05Z
  token_expires_at = 0001-01-01T00:00:00Z
  executor = "ssh"
  #known_hosts_file = "/home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/known_hosts"
  [runners.cache]
    MaxUploadedArchiveSize = 0
  [runners.ssh]
    user = "deploy"
    password = "redacted"
    host = "redacted.com"
    port = "22"
    identity_file = "/home/gitlab-runner/.ssh/id_rsa"
    disable_strict_host_key_checking = true
```

The `gitlab-runner` use can login successfully as deploy@redacted.com.

At gitlab.com CI console I see the same output than that of running gitlab-runner run locally on my droplet.
I'm at a loss here. I don't know how to debug this. I've used this setup in the past without trouble.